I need a Loop that Searches for Whole number in a column
I have a column with values such as



Column A




1


1.1


1.2


1.3


2


2.2


2.3


2.4



I would like a loop to check each cell and highlight the whole numbers 1 and 2 for example?
Dim lastrow As Integer
lastrow = Worksheets("BOM(Costing)").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

.find(What:=


Have you considered to use conditional formatting?

Using the formula =A1=INT(A1), you can apply conditional formatting, as in the following screenshot:


Just this, easy to control.

Thank you for such detailed advice on this, i am developing a major API Program so VBA is my way at the moment - until i hit the limits at least

@SolarMike: this might become an interesting use case: there is a situation, which might be rather difficult in VBA, but very easy in conditional formatting. But apparently the user is forced to use VBA. Is there a way to use VBA for determining whether or not a cell's formatting is impacted by VBA? In that case, the author might be helped here.

If you want to do it in VBA here is the code:
Data
Sub Search_Whole_numbers()

Dim lastrow As Integer
lastrow = Worksheets("BOM(Costing)").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row

Dim a As Integer
Dim num As Double
For a = 2 To lastrow 'Assuming your data has headers
    num = Cells(a, 1) 'Asssuming your data is in column "A"
    If num = Int(num) Then
        Cells(a, 1).Font.Color = vbRed 'This will set the cell to red
    End If
Next a

End Sub

Keep in mind, that numbers must have a comma not a full stop for this code to work.

"that numbers must have a comma not a full stop" - no, that's not true. Numbers have no "choice" of comma or full stop. The decimal separator is defined by the regional settings, numbers itself are stored in a binary format (independently of that regional settings). What you mean is that your code will work only if a cell contains numbers and not strings that look like numbers.

Hmm, i do not have such a deep knowledge about the regional settings etc. but am willing to learn more. My code works on values that are formatted as numbers and strings. Then I am not sure why the code encounters a "Type mismatch" error on the line num = Cells(a, 1)

Because probably that cell doesn't contain a number but a string. You don't need any knowledge about regional settings, a string is a string and a number is a number. That doesn't change if you change the formatting (or the number format).
